# CSS isolation in blazor-server components

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-component

with the new .NET 5 preview CSS isolation comes in blazor.
Does anybody know, is it possible to use the CSS isolation in blazor server?

I have play a lot around, but in my blazor server app CSS isolation doesn't work.
Or is this feature only available in blazor WebAssembly?

so I tried it:

- create a new blazor component, e.g. test.razor
- create component CSS file with name test.razor.css and write the CSS code in this file
- now start the blazor-server app, but no static CSS file will added and the CSS classes doesn't found.

TargetFramework is "net5.0".
installed dotnet version is "5.0.100-rc.2.20479.15".

greetings
Daniel

Comment: The template uses it by default in Server-side. For example `MainLayout.razor` and `MainLayout.razor.css`

Comment: i tried it exactly so, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ok i found the issue. In my "_Host.cshtml" file was the link to the "project.styles.css" missing:

```
<link href="ProjectName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

with this everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Also keep in mind that the `{ProjectName}` has to match `Solution > Project > Properties > Package > Product`. This may be different to the `Project` namespace.

Comment: This also worked for me, but is it anywhere in the documentation that this needs to be added for CSS isolation to work?

Comment: yes have a look at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-isolation-bundling

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 6.0 blazor server side, paste the following line:

```
<link href="ProjectName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

On the `Pages > _Layout.cshtml` file and it will work as expected.